# Getting current X, Y coordinate from a bezier curve moving object

Tags: python, math, bezier

I want to find the x, y coordinate of an object moving in a bezier curve after it moved for a certain amount of time.
I have included a simple graph of the object trajectory [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YprAB.png).
Consider the following known attributes of the object:

```
startingXY = [900, 450]
destinationXY = [-300, -600]
innerXY = [100, -50]
move_time = 15 # Moving duration in seconds
```

I tried using the below formula to calculate the (x,y), but it does not appear to be correct.

```
   def calculate(a, b, c, d, t):
        return math.pow(1 - t, 3) * a + 3 * t * math.pow(1 - t, 2) * b + 3 * math.pow(t, 2) * (1 - t) * c + math.pow(t, 3) * d
   
   t = (now - start_time) * 0.1
   x = calculate(0, startx, innerx, destinationx, t)
   y = calculate(0, starty, innery, destinationy, t)
```

I somewhat solved my problem with the following fomula:

```
    def the_math(a, b, c, t, p, f):
        return (math.pow((1 - t), 2) * a + 2 * math.pow((1 - t), t) * b + math.pow(t, 2) * c) + p * f
    
    elapsed_time = round(now - start)
    t = elapsed_time / self.config.move_time[fish.fish_type]
    x = the_math(path[0][0], path[1][0], path[2][0], t, 667, 0.85)
    y = the_math(path[0][1], path[1][1], path[2][1], t, 375, 0.8)
    print(x,y)
```

What would be a better formula to calculate the (x,y) coordinates?

Comment: If you have three coordinates, that's a quadratic curve. Your `calculate` is for a cubic curve. And to keep this readable, you definitely want `from math import pow` up top, so you can use `pow(t, 2)` directly instead of needing that `math.` prefix everywhere, if you want to use an explicit function. For ease of reading though, you probably want `**` instead of `pow`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.